# Tampermonkey in Chrome - How to use jquery without affecting the website at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey, userscripts

With `Tampermonkey` in `Google Chrome`, I want to be able to use `jquery` to `set/get` values but I need to make sure nothing is changed/added to the `dom`.

In simple words, I want `userscript` to be **absolutely invisible** to the affecting website.

Is the jquery that I added invisible to the website scope?

Another concern is, what if `jquery` is already present?

Did I do the `@grants` right?

Here is my try

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         test
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        *
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
// @grant GM_setValue
// @grant GM_getValue
// @grant GM_setClipboard
// @grant unsafeWindow
// @grant window.close
// @grant window.focus
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    //var $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery;
    var $ = window.jQuery;
    $(document).ready(Greasemonkey_main);

    function Greasemonkey_main ()
    {
    //$("#elem").val()    
    }


})();
```

Comment: If I understand the sandbox right, that *should* do what you're looking for. Are you having problems with it?

Comment: I understood I should use unsafeWindow.jQuery, but it doesn't work. I am not sure I understand @grant.

Comment: The simple fact of adding jQuery should not affect the webpage. Now, about `what if jquery is already present?`: I suggest you check it first with an `if` condition like `if(typeof($)!=="function"){// Add jQuery}`

Comment: `unsafeWindow.jQuery` will refer to the *original window*'s jQuery, I think. But if you have `@grant` with anything other than `none`, that should activate the sandbox, in which case referencing `window.jQuery` or just `jQuery` should point to the userscript's version, not the page's version

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Website checks if jquery is present. Thats why I am trying to use it 'anonimously'

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro That's the default text created by Tampermonkey when creating a new userscript

Comment: Unsure here... But I think the userscript are loading *after* the page has fully loaded. Anyway, you can apply a setTimeout to make sure....

Comment: And if the website checks for jQuery presence... It certainly will test the `$` variable. Using [`jQuery.noConflict()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/), you can use another custom variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have at least one `@grant` directive other than `none`, that will activate Tampermonkey's sandbox. This sandbox will result in `@require`d libraries assigning themselves to the *sandbox*'s `window`, rather than on the *native page*'s `window`, and referencing the `window` variable inside the userscript code will refer to the userscript's sandboxed `window` rather than the page's original `window`.

If you have `@grant none`, this will indicate *not* to use the sandbox, and `@require`s will result in properties being assigned to the original `window` (and referencing `window` inside the userscript will be referring to the original `window`).

Since you have a `@grant` which is enabling the sandbox, and you're referencing `window.jQuery`, that will reference the sandbox's version of jQuery, without doing anything to the page, so it should work as desired, regardless of whether jQuery is already on the *native* page or not. (Because you're in the sandbox, there shouldn't be any conflicts)